# Spring Security Prevent Multiple Login For Same User Not Working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, httpsession

I am working with a **Spring MVC** application with **Spring Security 4.x** as security framework. Now I am trying to **prevent multiple login for the same user** on different browser like Firefox and Google Chrome, but I don't know why it's not working for me. My implementation is as below:

```
@ComponentScan("com.application")
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secureUserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private LoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private LoginFailHandler loginFailHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobalSecurity(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(UrlMapping.getLoginUrl(), UrlMapping.getSignInUrl()).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager()).and().formLogin()
                .loginPage(UrlMapping.getLoginUrl()).loginProcessingUrl(UrlMapping.getSignInUrl())
                .failureUrl(UrlMapping.getSignInUrl()).failureHandler(loginFailHandler)
                .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler).usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage(UrlMapping.getUnauthorizedUrl()).and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID", "SESSION").invalidateHttpSession(true).and()
                .sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(15);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Bean
    public AccessDecisionManager accessDecisionManager() {
        List<AccessDecisionVoter<? extends Object>> decisionVoters = Arrays.asList(new WebExpressionVoter(),
                new RoleVoter(), new AuthenticatedVoter(), new MinuteBasedVoter());
        return new UnanimousBased(decisionVoters);
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
    }
}
```

Anyone please help or tell me if something is missing.

Comment: you'll need and can implement that behavior inside your user customAuthenticationProvider . In customAuthenticationProvider implement a behavior that if the end-user is already was authenticated then just throw an exception to indicate that the same user can't log in twice.

Comment: Without `preventLogin` on the session management it won't work. The first user will logout and the second will login. You are also using a custom `UserDetailsService` if you are using a custom `UserDetails` implementation as well a goog `hashcode` and `equals` implementation is required sa that is used to determine if it is the same user.

Comment: I have already override hasecode() and equals() method but still not able to prevent multiple login for same user.

Comment: Hi @Piyush Chaudhari. how do you solution for it? Can you explain for me. Thanks